# How do I listen for changes in Object fields that are added dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I wish to extend the Object and Array classes so that I will be able to listen to any changes made to their instances after construction.

The best I can do now is to add custom get and set functions for fields given at initialization/construction of an Instance:

```
var myObj = new CustomObject({name:'foo'});

myObj.name = 'bar'; // this will log "'name' in 'myObj' updated:'bar'"

//however:

myObj.age = 85; // this mutation will slip by unnoticed, 
                // since the 'age' field was never specified 
                // at initialization meaning no custom set / get 
                // functions where attached.
```

**Is there a way to achieve the following functionality?**

```
var myObj = new CustomObject();

myObj.name = 'foo';// this should log something like:
                   // "A new field 'name' was created for myObj with value 'foo'"
```

**Note:I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve polling.**

What I have now (resulting in the functionality shown in the first codeblock):

```
function CustomObject(data) {

    var that = this;

    for(var field in data){         
        prepField(field);                                   
    }

    function prepField(field){                  
        Object.defineProperty( that, field, {
            set: function(val){         
                data[field] = val;
                console.log(field,'in',that,'updated:',val);
            },
            get: function(){
                console.log(field,'in',that,'requested');
                return data[field];                 
            },
            enumerable:true
        });         
    }

    return this;

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to watch for *any* property?

Comment: yes exactly, in stead of listening for a predefined set of fields I would rather listen to the function that's being called to create new fields and set their values when I say myObj.randomfieldname = somevalue;

Comment: Okay, well I think you already know that but let me just say, there's no way in hell you're going to get anything like that to work and have moderately good browser support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox (mozilla) has something called `Proxy` that can do this.

[MDN Proxy docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

This is a non-standard feature currently, but appears as though it *(or something similar)* may become part of ECMAScript 6.

From http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proposals :

[image]

Comment: This does seem to be exactly what I'm looking for, however not exactly what I was hoping for (need more browser support) :(

Comment: thanks for helping me out though, I found another article about Proxy and Harmony: http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/proxies/ it's too bad only Firfox supports it now, I really wanted to make this with a complete solution. I guess a list of field names will have to be required for now.

Comment: @Marcus: You're welcome. Proxies are going to be great once they've gained support.